# How to write a proper unit test for ClassNotFoundExceptions?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I want to test a method where the following lines appear:

```
try (Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection()) {
        ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) connection).addDataType("geometry", Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));
        ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) connection).addDataType("box3d", Class.forName("org.postgis.PGbox3d"));

        try (Statement statement = connection.createStatement()) {
            /*
             * 4326 is the ID of a format in which the longitude and latitude values should be
             * retreived.
             */
            String sqlQuery = "SELECT ST_Transform(way, 4326) FROM planet_osm_line WHERE (highway='footway' OR highway='steps');";
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);

            while (resultSet.next()) {
                PGgeometry geom = (PGgeometry) resultSet.getObject(1);
                LineString line = (LineString) geom.getGeometry();
                Point[] wayPoints = line.getPoints();

                pointList.add(wayPoints);
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        throw new OpenStreetMapDAOException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

those lines force me to catch a `ClassNotFoundException`, i.e. the call of `Class.forName("name")` does so.

The `catch` case for the `ClassNotFoundException` is never reached in my tests since these classes are always present. **Is there a way to test my `catch` block?**

Comment: You can rewrite your code in such way that `Class.forName` will take some variable instead of harcoded values.

Comment: I found an even nicer solution. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored the code from my question till I ended up with the following method for the critical part, i.e those `Class.forName("some.class.name")` calls:

```
Statement createStatement() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();

    ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) connection).addDataType("geometry", Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));
    ((org.postgresql.PGConnection) connection).addDataType("box3d", Class.forName("org.postgis.PGbox3d"));

    return connection.createStatement();
}
```

In my unit tests I then used

```
when(dao.createStatement()).thenThrow(ClassNotFoundException.class);
```

which finally solved my problem.

Comment: Always glad to help, Mockito is a really nice tool for such stuff.

Answer (score 1):

As `org.postgresql.PGConnection` seems to be an interface, you could try to mock it via Mockito or a similar mocking framework.

```java
org.postgresql.PGConnection connection = Mockito.mock(org.postgresql.PGConnection.class)
Mockito.doThrow( ...your exception here...).when( connection ).addDataType("geometry", Class.forName("org.postgis.PGgeometry"));
```

With these two lines you are creating a mock object for your connection which you can then use in your method. This mock object will throw the given exception when that method is called with these parameters.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for but it got me on the right track. See my own answer below.